# Detect navigation action that moves between navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This is how my navigators are defined:

```
const navigatorA = TabNavigator({
    screenA :{screen: navigatorX},
    screenB: {screen: navigatorY},
});

const navigatorX = Stacknavigator({
     home: {screen: home},
      options: {screen: options},
});

const navigatorY = StackNavigator({
     profile: {screen: profile},
     settings :{ screen: settings}
})
```

I pass params like `this.props.navigation.navigate({routeName:'profile', params:{user:{thisUser}});`

I want to reset the navigation params when the user navigates back to the home screen from profile screen but not when the user navigate to the settings screen from the profile screen.

using `this.props.navigation.setParams({user:nulll});` in `componenWillUnmount` does not achieve the task as it resets the params even when user navigate from profile to settings.

I have tried using the `willBlur` event listener as well but it does not work in stack navigator and only tab navigators.

Comment: Do you click on any button to navigate back to home screen?

Comment: Do you want to send any data back to Home Screen from Settings Screen? Is this what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: I want to navigate from home to profile, from where I can navigate to settings.

Comment: @gaback its tab navigator so the tab for screenA

Comment: Have you try to use `componentWillReceiveProps()` on HomeScreen?